# Watering Hole Website NTLM Steal Attack

Tags: web-application, network, windows, smb, ntlm

I'm trying to recreate a Watering hole SMB theft attack where you send a victim a link to your website containing code like `file://ip/file.gif`.
Causing forced authentication which passes the NTLM hash.
I have the code which executes the process (check reference links).

**But how can I retrieve/steal the NTLM hash back over the internet remotely without being on the local network?**

This process can be done locally very easily but I'm struggling with finding an NTLM listener to use over the internet remotely on a website.

References:

- https://symantec-enterprise-blogs.security.com/blogs/threat-intelligence/leafminer-espionage-middle-east
- https://blog.lumen.com/newly-discovered-watering-hole-attack-targets-ukrainian-canadian-organizations/
- https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/xhunt-campaign-new-watering-hole-identified-for-credential-harvesting/

Comment: The links all clearly explain that the IP is your attacking server. The attacking server is on the internet. That's how you get it.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of attack you could use for example Responder.py
Please, bare in mind that in order to make it work over the internet it would be necessary to:

- Enable outbound SMB connections on the server that you plan to attack.
- NAT the port 445 on the attacker computer and ensure that no firewall is blocking it.

Once those two conditions are true you can now configure  Responder.py to enable a SMB server and after that start Responder.py.

Now you just need to test it accessing it.

Please, do not forget to close everything back once you have finished playing!

Comment: Will responder catch the NTLM hash of another pc of another router visiting the website?

Comment: As long as the "visiting" computer has outbound SMB connections enabled yes! It will grab it. Also it is worth mentioning that you will grab the Net-Ntlm hash, not the NTLM itself :-)